# Mute all sounds in a powerpoint presentation

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint

I am opening a ppt file from my desktop application in slideshow mode. I want to mute all the sounds that are embedded or linked with the presentation, if present. How can I mute the audio from the presentation?

I am using the following code to open the presentation.

```
Process pptProcess;
string appPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\powerpnt.exe";
string fileName = "D:\\Documents\\SamplePpt.pptx";
pptProcess = Process.Start(appPath, "/s " + fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking from the related [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.powerpoint/g8bh-jBx7u4):

> There's nothing like this in the object model.
>
> PowerPoint basically hands the sounds off to Windows to play, it
>   doesn't play  them itself.
>
> You might be able to make a copy of the PPT, visit each slide and
>   shape to  determine whether it has a transition/animation sound and if
>   so, whether it's  one you want to allow or not; if not, remove it.